# Calling a command-line application with conflicting arguments

Tags: java, linux, command-line

Specifically, this question is about Java and blktrace, but it can be generalized as following:

There is a command line application (blktrace) that can be called with parameters (specifically, format) or without. When called in default mode, this application returns one parameter that I need (starting block):

```
blktrace -d /dev/sda -o - | blkparse -i -

  8,0    0      144     0.011134344   524  I   W 819422 + 8 [kjournald]
```

But not another (IO size). I can add parameters (-f) to specify the latter parameter:

```
blktrace -d /dev/sda -o - | blkparse -f "%D %2c %8s %5T.%9t %5p %2a %3d %N\n" -i -

  8,0    0      237     2.013031115   524  I   W 4096
```

But doing so means I lose the former. The application is called from within a Java program.

I can't get both parameters from the application simultaneously. I can't run two instances of the application at the same time. I could run one instance after another, but that would mean my data isn't all compiled for the same IO sets.

Any idea how I could get both parameters for the same read/write operations?

Comment: What is the command you run and get these outputs?

Answer (score 1):

What about using following command where %S reports starting sector:

```
blktrace -d /dev/sda -o - | blkparse -f "%D %2c %8s %5T.%9t %5p %2a %3d %N %S\n" -i -
```

Comment: Are you certain that sector is the same as starting block?

Comment: I am not sure! But it should be so because there isn't any other related formatting command in `blkparse` [doc](http://linux.die.net/man/1/blkparse).